# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 not found

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm try to get sessionFactory bean in my Jtest then it's throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Spring.hibernate.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

my JtestCode:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:Spring.xml","classpath:Spring.hibernate.xml"});

    SessionFactory session=(SessionFactory) ac.getBean("sessionFactory");
    if(session==null){
        System.out.println("it's null");
    }

}
```

Here is my Spring.hibernate.xml:

```
<!-- JNDI方式配置数据源 -->
<!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> <property name="jndiName" value="${jndiName}"></property> </bean> -->

<!-- 配置数据源 -->
<bean name="dataSource" class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc_url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc_username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc_password}" />

    <!-- 初始化连接大小 -->
    <property name="initialSize" value="0" />
    <!-- 连接池最大使用连接数量 -->
    <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    <!-- 连接池最大空闲 -->
    <property name="maxIdle" value="20" />
    <!-- 连接池最小空闲 -->
    <property name="minIdle" value="0" />
    <!-- 获取连接最大等待时间 -->
    <property name="maxWait" value="60000" />

    <!-- <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" /> <property name="maxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize" value="33" /> -->

    <property name="validationQuery" value="${validationQuery}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />

    <!-- 配置间隔多久才进行一次检测，检测需要关闭的空闲连接，单位是毫秒 -->
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000" />
    <!-- 配置一个连接在池中最小生存的时间，单位是毫秒 -->
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="25200000" />

    <!-- 打开removeAbandoned功能 -->
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <!-- 1800秒，也就是30分钟 -->
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="1800" />
    <!-- 关闭abanded连接时输出错误日志 -->
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />

    <!-- 监控数据库 -->
    <!-- <property name="filters" value="stat" /> -->
    <property name="filters" value="mergeStat" />
</bean>

<!-- 配置hibernate session工厂 -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Did I forget to add jar or which jar that include org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean? .I need someone help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `org.springframework.orm-N.N.N.jar` in your classpath?

Have a good look at the error message, make sure there aren't other Spring or external libraries as pre-requisites -- which would cause an indirect ClassNotFoundError.

Comment: then throws another error :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

Comment: That would probably be `org.springframework.beans-*.jar`.  You may also need `core`, `transaction`, `asm` or `jdbc` jars -- plus others if you're doing webapps. Perhaps a +1 or my answer would be appreciated.

Comment: thank U. my spring -core 's version is low..so I replaced it.I need more reputation so...^^

Comment: Try and keep all Spring jars from the same version, you'll always be chasing incompatabilities & errors if you're mixing versions. Thx!

Comment: <!-- Spring ORM -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: add the above to your pom.xml